# Add swiperefreshlayout/ custom pull to refresh in AppBarLayout(CoordinatorLayout Setup)

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

How do I add swipetorefresh on the appbar inside a coodinatorlayout setup?

I have added my xml below. With this layout setup I pull to refresh or swipe to refresh  on the appbar does not seem to work.

Is it possible to implement this or am I missing something?

Does swipetorefresh work only with a recylerview?

Is the coordinatorlayour causing issues?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@color/dodger_blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_home_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dummyData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

EDIT:

Added the requested xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="110dp">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="110dp"
android:background="@color/dodger_blue"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testMediumTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_hud_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/snow"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:text="test Care Team" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_hud_actions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_one"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_light"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_group" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_one_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_one"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/snow"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="Consult Coach" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_one_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_one"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_two"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_light"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_group" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_two_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_two"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/snow"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="Consult Expert" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_two_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_two"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_three"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_light"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_group" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_three_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_three"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/snow"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="Consult Doctor" />

        <com.test_rohan.homelayoutpoc.testRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_three_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_three"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dodger_blue"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_default_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_toolbar"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/default_hud_banner"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: post xml of ' layout_home_toolbar' also

Comment: Added the requested xml

Comment: Remove SwipeRefreshLayout inside appbar layout. The latter one is correct. 
`Does swipetorefresh work only with a recylerview? Answer is No :  The SwipeRefreshLayout should be used whenever the user can refresh the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture and can only support one direct child`

Comment: @Sanny . Yes I moved the swiperefresh to the included layout. But it still doesnt work. Only if the recyclerview below has scrolled a bit then on quick return of the appbar I can swipetorefresh. If the recyclerview that is below is not scrolled at all, swipe to refresh doesnt work

Comment: @RohanM also check the usage of collaspingToolbar . >CollapsingToolbarLayout is a wrapper for {@link Toolbar} which implements a collapsing app bar.
 * It is designed to be used as a direct child of a {@link AppBarLayout}.

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` only supports a single `ListView` or `GridView` child.

Please see this: https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

Comment: If you put SwipeRefreshLayout  as a parent of a linearlayout is works as well.I think when that is coupled with a coordinatorlayout it causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SwipeRefreshLayout` from `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. So should look like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <include
            layout="@layout/layout_home_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dummyData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I need to swipe to refresh(or add a custom pull-to-refresh) only to the appbar.

Comment: I am not whether SRL is designed to work inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Because the scroll offset has not send to parent coordinator layout. The scroll offset is calculate by the AppBarLayout itself to do offset scroll.
If you want to add refresh for AppBarLayout, you can try the repo [nestrefresh](https://github.com/ToDou/nestrefresh). Use RefreshBarLayout to do pull refresh.